# Laravel add custom middleware to route group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

in my web application i have admin panel and i'm trying to make access to users that they have admin role by this code:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class CheckUserAdminRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            if (auth()->check() && !auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
                auth()->logout();
                return redirect(route('system.messages','userIsNotAdmin'));
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and in my routs i have this route group:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth:web'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    $this->group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function () {
        $this->get('panel', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

my kernel:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserAdminRole::class,
];
```

now when i add my middleware as `CheckUserAdminRole` to route group like with this code:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth:web','CheckUserAdminRole'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
```

i get this error:

```
Class CheckUserAdminRole does not exist
```

this codes couldn't resolve my problem:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of registering your middleware in the `$middleware` array, you should register it in `$routeMiddleware` like so:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'checkAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserAdminRole::class,
];
```

*Note: registering a middlware in the `$middleware` array results in it being executed for **every** request and therefore is not applicable on specific routes.*

Then you can use it in your routes with the `checkAdmin` name:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth:web','checkAdmin'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

Answer (score 16):

You can also use middleware and route group together easily like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    //All the routes that belongs to the group goes here
    Route::get('dashboard', function() {} );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple fix without touching the `Kernel` file and taking advantage of the `Policy`. The `accessAdmin` is a function created inside `Policy` file.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware' => 'can:accessAdmin, App\User', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
$this->group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function () {
    $this->get('panel', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can try middleware with prefix and groups.

```
Route::middleware(['Auth'])->prefix('api/')->group(function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'review/'], function () {
       Route::get('/', 'User\Controllers\Api\UserController@getUserReviews');
    });
});
```

**Hope its helps**